# Alternating formulas on odd /even rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write one formula on even rows and a different formula on odd rows in the same column.  Searching this site I found the following code:

```
Sub OddRowAlert()
With Range("B16:B100")
    .Formula = "=IF((MOD(ROW(B16),2)),""Odd"",""Even"")"
    .Formula = .Value
End With
End Sub
```

This works with text or simple formulas.  However, when I replace "Odd" or "Even" with my formula I receive a

> run time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
Sub Daily_Analysis()
'
' Daily_Analysis Macro
'
Lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("L7:L" & Lastrow).Formula = "=Text(A7,""dddd"")"

With Range("M7:M" & Lastrow)
    .Formula = "=IF((MOD(ROW(M7),2)),""=IFS(L7=""Saturday"","""",L7=""Sunday"","""",L7<>L6,""Number of times over 75%"",L7=L6,"""")"",""=IFS(L7=""Saturday"","""",L7=""Sunday"","""",L6<>L5,COUNTIFS(D7:D103,"">75%"",K7:K103,""Working"")+COUNTIFS(G7:G103,"">75%"",K7:K103,""Working""),L6=L5,"""")"")"
    .Formula = .Value
End With

With Range("N7:N" & Lastrow)
     .Formula = "=IF((MOD(ROW(N7),2)),""=IFS(L7=""Saturday"","""",L7=""Sunday"","""",L7<>L6,""Percentage of the day"",L7=L6,"""")"",""=IFS(L7=""Saturday"","""",L7=""Sunday"","""",L7<>L6,M8/COUNTIFS(K7:K102,""working"",L7:L102,L7),L7=L6,"""")"")"
     .Formula = .Value
End With

With Range("O7:O" & Lastrow)
     .Formula = "=IF((MOD(ROW(O7),2)),""=IFS(L7=""Saturday"","""",L7=""Sunday"","""",L7<>L6,""hours of poor performance"",L7=L6,"""")"",""=IFS(L7=""Saturday"","""",L7=""Sunday"","""",L7<>L6,(15*M8)/60,L7=L6,"""")"")"
     .Formula = .Value
End With

'
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't have that `=` in front of `IFS` within the formula. Always helps to `Debug.Print` the formula to make sure it's what you want before attempting to write it to the cell.

Comment: nor the `""` surrounding the `IFS`

Comment: @ScottCraner yep, just caught that too, followed my own advice instead of just eyeballing the formula lol.

Comment: Ahh, it's all about setting expectations I suppose.   I was receiving the results of the formula when I removed the surrounding "" and the ='s.  What I was expecting was to have the resultant formulas of the   If(mod)   written to the cells as the .Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, nested formula do not get `""` surrounding them and no `=`, just nest them:

```
Sub Daily_Analysis()
'
' Daily_Analysis Macro
'
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ActiveSheet.Range("L7:L" & Lastrow).Formula = "=Text(A7,""dddd"")"

With ActiveSheet.Range("M7:M" & Lastrow)
    .Formula = "=IF((MOD(ROW(M7),2)),IFS(L7=""Saturday"","""",L7=""Sunday"","""",L7<>L6,""Number of times over 75%"",L7=L6,""""),IFS(L7=""Saturday"","""",L7=""Sunday"","""",L6<>L5,COUNTIFS(D7:D103,"">75%"",K7:K103,""Working"")+COUNTIFS(G7:G103,"">75%"",K7:K103,""Working""),L6=L5,""""))"
    .Value = .Value
End With

With ActiveSheet.Range("N7:N" & Lastrow)
     .Formula = "=IF((MOD(ROW(N7),2)),IFS(L7=""Saturday"","""",L7=""Sunday"","""",L7<>L6,""Percentage of the day"",L7=L6,""""),IFS(L7=""Saturday"","""",L7=""Sunday"","""",L7<>L6,M8/COUNTIFS(K7:K102,""working"",L7:L102,L7),L7=L6,""""))"
     .Value = .Value
End With

With ActiveSheet.Range("O7:O" & Lastrow)
     .Formula = "=IF((MOD(ROW(O7),2)),IFS(L7=""Saturday"","""",L7=""Sunday"","""",L7<>L6,""hours of poor performance"",L7=L6,""""),IFS(L7=""Saturday"","""",L7=""Sunday"","""",L7<>L6,(15*M8)/60,L7=L6,""""))"
     .Value = .Value
End With

'
End Sub
```

---

BTW pulling out the like items and rearranging we can shorten the formulas:

```
Sub Daily_Analysis()
'
' Daily_Analysis Macro
'
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ActiveSheet.Range("L7:L" & Lastrow).Formula = "=Text(A7,""dddd"")"

With ActiveSheet.Range("M7:M" & Lastrow)
    .Formula = "=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A7,2)>5,l7=l6),"""",IF(Mod(row(),2),""Number of times over 75%"",COUNTIFS(D7:D103,"">75%"",K7:K103,""Working"")+COUNTIFS(G7:G103,"">75%"",K7:K103,""Working"")))"
    .Value = .Value
End With

With ActiveSheet.Range("N7:N" & Lastrow)
     .Formula = "=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A7,2)>5,l7=l6),"""",IF(Mod(row(),2),""Percentage of the day"",M8/COUNTIFS(K7:K102,""working"",L7:L102,L7)))"
     .Value = .Value
End With

With ActiveSheet.Range("O7:O" & Lastrow)
     .Formula = "=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A7,2)>5,l7=l6),"""",IF(Mod(row(),2),""hours of poor performance"",L7<>L6,(15*M8)/60))"
     .Value = .Value
End With

'
End Sub
```

Comment: The second of the two examples works strangely, and I'm not good enough yet to understand why.  The First example gives me what I asked for (though that isn't actually what I need, I have since learned)